# Dynamic parameterized query with like

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

The Normal assignment operator is working fine but like operation is not working with below query in a Stored Procedure, Could you correct what is wrong with the query?

On changing only to LIKE Operator below query based procedure throws exception

```
AND APP_FRAMES.APP_EXT_CODE =:IN_APP_EXT_CODE%;      -- working

AND APP_FRAMES.APP_EXT_CODE LIKE %:IN_APP_EXT_CODE%; -- not working
```

**Working Code:**

```
QUERY_STR := 'select * from APP_FRAME_PROPERTIES,APP_FRAMES
Where APP_FRAME_PROPERTIES.APP_EXT_CODE = APP_FRAMES.APP_EXT_CODE
AND APP_FRAMES.APP_EXT_CODE =:IN_APP_EXT_CODE';

OPEN OUT_RESULT FOR QUERY_STR USING IN_APP_EXT_CODE;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to concatenate the `'%'` literals:

```
AND APP_FRAMES.APP_EXT_CODE LIKE '%' || :IN_APP_EXT_CODE || '%';
```

The whole query would be:

```
QUERY_STR := 'select * from APP_FRAME_PROPERTIES,APP_FRAMES
Where APP_FRAME_PROPERTIES.APP_EXT_CODE = APP_FRAMES.APP_EXT_CODE
AND APP_FRAMES.APP_EXT_CODE LIKE ''%'' || :IN_APP_EXT_CODE || ''%'' ';
```

Comment: Thanks for answer,those are inside of the string so no need of any extra characters, right ?

Comment: QUERY_STR := 'select * from APP_FRAME_PROPERTIES,APP_FRAMES
Where APP_FRAME_PROPERTIES.APP_EXT_CODE = APP_FRAMES.APP_EXT_CODE
AND APP_FRAMES.APP_EXT_CODE ''%'':IN_APP_EXT_CODE''%'';

Comment: @sunleo, seems to be correct, if you add the `LIKE` keyword, and the `||` vertical bars.

Comment: Perfect, could you tell me whey || is needed here? any reference or doc link would be appreciatable.

Comment: Please tell me what is the exact usage of || here because already query is just in the string format.

Comment: @sunleo, if you want to LIKE search for `'abc'`, you do `LIKE '%abd%'`. The `||` are there to concatenate the `%`  characters and variable content, into the format LIKE expects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103273/discussion-between-sunleo-and-jarlh).

Comment: @sunleo - it's [the concatenation operator](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/operators003.htm). if that's the doc link you're after.