# How to display records from a table ordered as in the where clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, sql-order-by, where-clause

I am trying to display the records,order as in the where clause..
example:

```
select name from table where name in ('Yaksha','Arun','Naveen');
```

It displays `Arun,Naveen,Yaksha (alphabetical order)` 
I want display it as same order `i.e 'Yaksha''Arun','Naveen'` 
how to display this...
I am using `oracle` db.

Comment: Did you miss `,` btwn `'Yaksha''Arun'`??

Comment: Are you using a fixed list of values or is it variable - in which case where are the values coming from?

Comment: @Praveen, I m using , between

Comment: @Alex,I m checking in variable list.

Comment: But where is the list from, and what form does it take? Are you being passed a collection of values, or a single comma-separated string that you're manipulating? You've simplified to ask your question which is generally fine, but more context is probably important here, to see what options you have.

Comment: @Charan non of the below answers solved your issue??

Answer (score 4):

Add this `ORDER BY` at the query's end:

```
order by case name when 'Yaksha' then 1
                   when 'Arun'   then 2
                   when 'Naveen' then 3
         end
```

(There's no other way to get that order. You need an ORDER BY to get a specific result set order.)

Answer (score 2):

It may be a bit clunky, but you can create a custom ordering with a `case` expression:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     my_table
WHERE    name IN ('Yaksha', 'Arun','Naveen')
ORDER BY CASE name WHEN 'Yaksha' THEN 1
                   WHEN 'Arun'   THEN 2
                   WHEN 'Naveen' THEN 3
         END ASC
```

A slightly longer option, but one that prevents duplication of the string literals is to use a subquery:

```
SELECT   m.*
FROM     my_table m
JOIN     (SELECT 'Yaksha' AS name, 1 AS name_order FROM dual
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 'Arun' AS name, 2 AS name_order FROM dual
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 'Naveen' AS name, 3 AS name_order FROM dual) o 
         ON o.name = m.name
ORDER BY o.name_order ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with something like the following:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     test
WHERE    name IN (  'Yaksha', 'Arun', 'Naveen'  )
ORDER BY instr ( q'['Yaksha', 'Arun', 'Naveen']', name ) ASC
```

This way could be useful if your IN list is somehow dynamic.

Comment: Does instr return each name's position? What's the q's purpose?

Comment: Yes, the idea was that INSTR gives the position, thus ordering according to the IN string; the q' only was to avoid any manipulation on the string, in case it was dynamically generated

Comment: @jarlh - The `q` denotes the [alternative quoting mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218), which saves having to escape the single quotes. (Might have been useful [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35358119/266304) *8-)

Answer (score 2):

If the list of values is dynamic or you just don't want to repeat the values you could use (or abuse, depending on your point of view) a table collection, and join your real table to a [table collection expression](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#i2104990) instead of using `IN`:

```
select your_table.name
from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('Yaksha','Arun','Naveen')) t
join your_table on your_table.name = t.column_value;
```

Which will generally work, but of course without an order-by clause is not *guaranteed* to work, so you can use an inline view to assign the order:

```
select your_table.name from (
  select row_number() over (order by null) as rn, column_value as name
  from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('Yaksha','Arun','Naveen'))
) t
join your_table on your_table.name = t.name
order by t.rn;
```

This still relies on `row_number() over (order by null)` using the order of the elements in the collection; which relies on collection unnesting preserving the element order. I don't think that's guaranteed either, so there is still some risk involved.

Comment: +1 Though there is a risk involved, but it completely answers OP's requirement which needs dynamic values. Of course, it can't be generalized, since a generic answer is out of scope of existing question.